# Enable avatars in Gerrit 2.12

Tags: gerrit

According to the Gerrit [documentation](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-review-ui.html) it should be possible to set avatars for user accounts, but there is no description on how to do this.

> If avatars are configured on the server, the avatar image of the comment author is displayed in the top left corner...

Right now all I see is a "blank image" and no avatar. How do I enable this feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data sources for the avatar images are realized by plugins. There currently exist the [following plugins](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/#/admin/projects/?filter=avatar):

- [avatars-external](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/avatars-external/+/master/src/main/resources/Documentation): Enables to set a custom URL to load avatars from.
- [avatars-gravatar](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/avatars-gravatar/+/master/src/main/resources/Documentation): Plugin to display user icons from [Gravatar](https://www.gravatar.com).

If you cannot point Gerrit to a user-specific URL (i.e. `https://example.com/avatars/{username}.jpg`) and don't want to use images from [Gravatar](https://www.gravatar.com), then you can write your own plugin.

I promise, it's not hard.. I managed to create `avatars-external` :-)

Comment: Thanks! Strange that a feature has been included (and partially enabled), but requires a (custom) plugin to make it work...

Comment: You're reading the end user documentation. But administrator's documentation is much clearer and only mentions them in the [Plugins list](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-plugins.html). I think improvements to the documentation are welcome ;-)

Comment: Not just documentation, but implementation of the feature as well. If there is space reserved for an avatar, add a default one and make it possible for the user to change it. That's not an admin task unless you integrate with AD/Lync kind of tools.

Comment: I agree that it's weird that even requests (to `/accounts/{email}/avatar`) are made, although no avatar plugin is enabled (see [issue](https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=1987)). However, I can't follow that "there is space reserved for an avatar" (when e.g. looking at [this gerrit](https://gerrit.onosproject.org/#/c/7718/)). But we're getting OT.